# mail() function is not working in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

When I try to send a test mail from prestashop backend, it shows an error, as follows:

**Error: please check your configuration
Sending failed using mail() as PHP's default mail() function returned boolean FALSE.**

Is there any fix available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as said, check your configuration... Or contact the host of your Web server (or their docs!) to see how to activate this function.
Some hosts are quite restrictive (by default at least) and don't offer all requirements out of the box.